# Uncaught ReferenceError: *< the function is here>* is not defined in react, what Im I doing wrong here?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an ingredients list with an input bar.I just started to learn react so I'm really a noob.

The console says ListManager is not defined. I couldn't find any syntax error, but I could've just missed them for all I know.

ListManager.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var List = require('./List.jsx');

var ListManager = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {items:[], newItemText:''};

  },

  onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({newItemText: e.target.value});
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefualt();

      var currentItems = this.state.items;

      currentItems.push(this.state.newItemText);

      this.setState({items: currentItems, newItemText: ''});

  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>
          {this.props.title}
        </h3>
        <form onSubmit ={this.handleSubmit}>
         <input  onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.newItemText} />
         <button>Add</button>
        </form>
        <List items ={this.state.items} />

      </div>
    );

  }
});

module.exports = ListManager;
```

List.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ListItem = require('./ListItem.jsx');

var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var createItem = function(text, index)  {
            return <ListItem key = {index + text} text = {text} />;
        };
      return (
        <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>);
    }
});

module.exports = List;
```

The console error states:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ListManager is not defined

Comment: You have a typo in the `handleSubmit: function` - it should be `e.preventDefault()` - but I dunno if that is the cause for the error.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie thanks a lot. I missed that one!! I found another error in my main.jsx file.The typo and the other error together was throwing the exception.

Comment: Glad you figured it out